# Add a line break to an erb tooltip?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, tooltip, erb

I have an erb object with a tooltip:

```
<%= link_to "hover-me", "#", title:"line1<br>line2"%>
```

but the tooltip just displays like this:

```
line1<br>line1
```

How can I add a linebreak to an erb-generated tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTML in the title won't work, try replacing `<br>` with `&#13;`:

```
<%= link_to "hover-me", "#", title:"line1&#13;line2"%>
```

Tested in Safari and Chrome, it worked.